# Simple reverse proxy for old printer with old SSL

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy

My printer is an old trusty workhorse. It does, however, not support newer TLS, and the manufacturer has long forgotten they ever made the model and thus there is no new firmware. In fact it is so old that modern browsers hold their noses in disgust and refuse to talk to it.

How can I set up a simple basic reverse proxy, which I can connect to with a modern browser and which connects to my printer using the ciphers below?

Performance does not matter. Unencrypted traffic is acceptable.

I am hoping for something like:

```
$ myproxycommand --backend https://printer.tange.dk \
    --accept-old-ciphers --bindport 8080
```

And the be able to use: `localhost:8080` in the browser.

```
$ sslscan --no-failed --tls1 printer.tange.dk
                   _
           ___ ___| |___  ___ __ _ _ __
          / __/ __| / __|/ __/ _` | '_ \
          \__ \__ \ \__ \ (_| (_| | | | |
          |___/___/_|___/\___\__,_|_| |_|

                  Version 1.8.2
             http://www.titania.co.uk
        Copyright Ian Ventura-Whiting 2009

Testing SSL server printer.tange.dk on port 443

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
    Accepted  TLSv1  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA

  Prefered Server Cipher(s):
    TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
```

Comment: Since unencrypted traffic is acceptable, why not use HTTP?

Comment: The printer redirects HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: You might be able to do something with `socat` as it has `openssl,method=TLSv1` but it is outside my domain of knowledge.